# webservice sample code or easy to follow documentation

Tags: iphone, web-services

I want to learn on web services with iPhone/ipad. Any simple and educational samples or ducumentation or books you may recommend?
Thanks 
Saro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, please see:

http://iphonebyradix.blogspot.com/2011/04/working-with-webservices.html

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/06/web-services-core.html

http://mtgr8.users.sourceforge.net/

http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/09/creating-an-iphone-based-web-s.html

http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/

Alternately, there are numerous hits when you search SO for [iphone webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Biphone%5D%20webservice) .